# Make a summary of a Calculated variable with Group By Proc SQL on SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I want to make a summary of the **MT_REMBOURSE_RN** variable calculated in the Proc SQL statement and output that sum for each Group declared in the Group by statement into the **MT_REMBOURSE_RN_Tot**.

This the code made :

```
proc sql undo_policy=none;
    create table tab_actif3 (compress=Yes) as 
        select a.*,
                (-sum(a.vb_cc_inclus)) as VM,

                intrr(1,calculated VM,  CF_1,CF_2   
                                    ) as X_Spread,

                 (sum(1, calculated X_Spread))**(-Nb_An_Int) as SPREAD_DF,
                 INT_NETS_RECUS_PAYES* calculated SPREAD_DF  as INT_NETS_RECUS_PAYES_RN,
                 MT_REMBOURSE* calculated SPREAD_DF as MT_REMBOURSE_RN,
                 sum( calculated MT_REMBOURSE_RN) as MT_REMBOURSE_RN_Tot


            from tab_actif2 as a

            Left join  tab_actif_CF2 (rename=(NoSetScenario=NoSetScenario1 Institution=Institution1
            Classe_Actif_s=Classe_Actif_s1 Canton=Canton1 Code_Isin_S=Code_Isin_S1)) as B
                On A.NoSetScenario = B.NoSetScenario1 and
                   A.institution = B.Institution1 and
                   A.Classe_Actif_s = B.Classe_Actif_s1 and
                   A.Canton = B.Canton1 and
                   A.Code_Isin_S = B.Code_Isin_S1

            Group by NoSetScenario,
                   institution, 
                   Classe_Actif_s ,
                   Canton, 
                   Code_Isin_S,
                    Nom_Choc;



quit;
```

But I have got that error :

```
ERROR: Summary functions nested in this way are not supported.
```

Is it possible to achieve that goal in the same Proc SQL without making another proc SQL statement calling tab_actif3 ?

Comment: Try replacing `a.*` with the columns explicitly in the `group by`.  Your query is probably not valid SQL (if there are any columns in `a` that are not in the `group by`).  `proc sql` allows it through something called "re-merging"; however, my guess is that is where the problem lies.

Comment: I want to keep all variable from ```a ``` (which is tab_actif2) and not just the columns in the ```group by```. I just want to add two new columns (```MT_REMBOURSE_RN``` not present  at the beginning in ```a ``` but calculated in the proc SQL, and  output the sum for each group in the columns ``` MT_REMBOURSE_RN_Tot``` )

Comment: Is that your full code and log? Can you please post your full log. At first glance I don't see an issue.

Comment: I wonder if you have a no sql automatic remerge option selected somewhere. SAS is doing it for you, but its essentially the same as having multiple queries from a computational perspective.

Comment: Is the input, tab_actif2, an actual table or is it a view?

Comment: this is an actual table. And you are totally right this isn't my full code. it's a simplification of my real code.

Comment: Why are you renaming the join variables in alias B? The code is not selecting any of those renamed variables.  For clarity and sanity I would recommend adding the alias prefix A. or B. to each of the variables in the complex select formulas.  You might need to have to 'bulk' of the query (an aggregate query with remerge) as a sub-select, and the new containing outer scope would perform the final aggregate with remerge.

Answer (score 1):

Problem understood!! 
This is a specificity of SAS SQL programming. You can not make a `sum()` linked to a `Group by` statement in a proc SQL after a regular `sum` function which makes an addition of variables for each observation in the table. This creates processing confusion at runtime.

For instance in my code:
 `(-sum(a.vb_cc_inclus)) as VM` related to the `Group By`, which is done before the normal sum statement  `(sum(1, calculated X_Spread))**(-Nb_An_Int)` doesn't bring any problem when the code is running without the second sum `sum( calculated MT_REMBOURSE_RN)` related to the `Group by` as well.

Thus, the second `Group by` related sum, used after the normal sum, ought to be made in another `create table`.